# how to display range slider value in in 12 hour day time format in android

Tags: android

This is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
        android:id="@+id/range_slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:thumbColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:thumbRadius="12dp"
        app:trackColorActive="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:trackHeight="4dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Activity Class:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.rovedashcam.android.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.custom_date_picker_title.range_slider

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            val startTime = 0f // Start time (in minutes since midnight)
            val endTime = (24 * 60).toFloat()// End time (in minutes since midnight)
            val timeInterval = 15f // Time interval (in minutes)
    
            range_slider.valueFrom = startTime
            range_slider.valueTo = endTime
    
            range_slider.stepSize = timeInterval
            range_slider.values = mutableListOf(startTime, endTime)
    
            // Handle the range slider changes
            range_slider.addOnChangeListener { _, _, _ ->
                val startMinute = range_slider.values[0].toInt()
                val endMinute = range_slider.values[1].toInt()
    
                val startHour = startMinute / 60
                val startMinuteRemainder = startMinute % 60
                val endHour = endMinute / 60
                val endMinuteRemainder = endMinute % 60
    
                val startTime = String.format(
                    "%02d:%02d %s",
                    if (startHour == 0 || startHour == 12) 12 else startHour % 12,
                    startMinuteRemainder,
                    if (startHour < 12) "AM" else "PM"
                )
                val endTime = String.format(
                    "%02d:%02d %s",
                    if (endHour == 0 || endHour == 12) 12 else endHour % 12,
                    endMinuteRemainder,
                    if (endHour < 12) "AM" else "PM"
                )
                Log.d("Time Interval", "$startTime--$endTime");
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Using this i am able to display "Time Interval" in 12 hour format when i change slide range bar but I want to display start steps and end steps in 12 hour time format  on start slide top and end slide top but its accept only float  value so can any one help me how to achieve this

Expected UI

[image]

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to achieve? Can you share a screenshot or explain a bit better?

Comment: Expected value should : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2B7D.png 
Currently : https://pasteboard.co/AQJtyoZSlcuo.png
I want to show steps view with string value in 12 hour time format but its showing float value

Comment: @tomerpacific basically we want to show eject time value like first screen expected UI but in second screen value is showing in float value because range_slider.values expect only float not string or time so i want to show value in time format when i slide from 0 to 23:59 . 

THanks